# ¿Sería oportuno no permitir publicar una pregunta hasta que se gane al menos la medalla Informado?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, usuarios-nuevos, medallas, privilegios

Ahora mismo antes de publicar esto, he mirado las preguntas más recientes y en las 3 primeras páginas (15 publicaciones por página) hay 5 preguntas de usuarios sin una sola medalla y esas 5 preguntas puestas en espera.

¿Sería oportuno **no permitir publicar** una pregunta hasta que ganen la medalla de [Informado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) al menos?

Normal que estén cerradas dichas preguntas si no saben cómo preguntar.

Me han comentado en el chat que es cierto que mucha gente pasa el recorrido sin mirarlo y que tener la medalla no implica nada. Pero al menos saben de su existencia y si se les cierra la pregunta teniendo la medalla al menos es cosa suya por no haberlo leído detenidamente. Aunque como las leyes, el desconocimiento de las mismas no te exime de su cumplimiento.

Ejemplos:

- [¿Cómo eliminar caracteres de un String en un intervalo de tiempo para que parezca una animación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33600/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-caracteres-de-un-string-en-un-intervalo-de-tiempo)
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33550/problema-con-css
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33537/quisiera-saber-que-atributos-pueden-llevar-las-tablas-tipo-cliente-y-tipo-factu
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33529/android-xml-vector-drawable-problem-in-android-nougat-and-above
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33485/pascal-array-y-sus-partes
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33482/ejercicio-sobre-pascal
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33480/crashing-app-when-press-hardware-back-button-and-close-app-iam-using-navigation
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33478/java-lang-classcastexception-modelo-subtema-cannot-be-cast-to-modelo-pregunta
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33424/limimitar-compras-de-usuarios-a-un-solo-producto-en-prestashop
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33396/creaci%C3%B3n-de-la-clase-que-represente-un-color

Comment: Coincido totalmente en pensar una estrategia para poder facilitar que los nuevos usuarios entiendan cómo preguntar y no se les cierre las preguntas, obteniendo una buena interacción. Sin embargo, si bien el [tour] describe brevemente que tiene que estar dentro de la temática, no veo que sea suficiente para entender realmente cómo preguntar.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar cuáles son esas preguntas?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza puedo, aunque lo evité para no señalar a nadie. Basta con mirar en la lista de preguntas recientes. Si quieres, pongo algunas

Comment: Preferiría que las pongas todas. Quisiera revisar con más detalle los casos a los que te refieres.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza editado. alguna más habria que ya consiguió 1 medalla

Comment: Tener la medalla no implica que hayas leído la guía... siguiente `->` siguiente `->` siguiente `->` aceptar.

Comment: Corregí el formato de la lista de viñetas. Me parece que los enlaces que muestran el URL y n o el título de la pregunta son enlaces a preguntas que han sido eliminadas.

Answer (score 6):

No, no sería oportuno.

Lo que aparece en el recorrido no son unas normas especiales para preguntar en SO. Son indicaciones de sentido común. A muchas personas no nos hace falta que nos digan que nuestras preguntas deben ser claras y deben de contener los elementos necesarios para que se puedan responder.
La temática del sitio sí es algo específico que no puedes conocer sin leer en el sitio específico. Diferentes sitios en Internet diferentes temáticas. Pero hay muchas formas de conocerla sin haber ganado ninguna medalla.

Además, esa medida no tendría ningún efecto. De la misma forma que se pulsa en aceptar las condiciones de uso del software sin leerlas en la mayoría de casos también nos encontraríamos con que los usuarios pulsan avanzar página en el recorrido sin leerla.

El principal problema de las malas preguntas no es el desconocimiento del usuario. El principal problema es **la falta de esfuerzo**. Que me lo den todo hecho. Y eso es algo que no se puede arreglar con ninguna herramienta automática. Poner un comentario explicando qué problema tiene la pregunta e indicando que si se resuelve probablemente obtenga respuesta es la medida apropiada. Una medida que cuesta tiempo y esfuerzo. Véase por ejemplo el [comentario de Awes0meM4n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33600/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-caracteres-de-un-string-en-un-intervalo-de-tiempo-para-que-parezc#comment55654_33600), el mismo usuario ha editado su pregunta hasta dejarla bien. Moderadores así es lo que necesitamos.

Y no nos olvidemos de votar. Los votos dan vida al sitio.

Answer (score 4):

9 meses después, aun coincido, **no sería oportuno**.

De una [pregunta más reciente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2244/se-podr%C3%ADa-hacer-m%C3%A1s-participativa-e-inmersiva-la-experiencia-de-la-p%C3%A1gina-de-re) con diferente titulo, pero que es básicamente lo mismo, cito:

> La lectura del tour no garantiza la comprensión -> la comprensión del
>   tour no garantiza la calidad. Por la graduación perdimos muchos
>   revisores, pero poco a poco el número se irá recuperando y revisaremos
>   más rápido. - toledano

---

> Seguirán exisitiendo usuarios que aunque se avienten el recorrido no
>   sepan ni cómo hacer una pregunta ni poco acercada a lo decente. Lo que
>   sí podemos hacer es orientarlos a agregar segmentos de código,
>   resultados esperados, a tomar el recorrido, a revisar el centro de
>   ayuda, considero que eso es mejor que forzar a alguien a ver una
>   página que no se sabe si tiene el tiempo o las ganas de revisar. -
>   Flxtr

---

> Concuerdo con @Flxtr, mejor orientar a cada usuario que restringir. -
>   Muriano

---

Y si la comunidad resolviera que si es oportuno, creo que **no se resolvería el problema de fondo**, el cual fue expuesto muy bien por Jose Antonio Dura Olmos.

Pienso que deberiamos encontrar formas de que los usuarios con la reputación debida nos ayuden más en las revisiones y la moderación, y como último recurso <sup>1</sup> **considerar seriamente ideas tan buenas** como [la que expuso NekoOS hace ya más de un mes y que no recibió la atención debida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/es-posible-implementar-una-nueva-caracteristica-que-gu%C3%ADe-en-el-proceso-de-crear).

---

<sup>1</sup> Digo último, porque no sé que tan díficil sería implementar algo así, a quien se le tiene que pedir permiso o que. Pero de que la idea es buena, si es buena, quizas la mejor para tratar este tema tan recurrente en el sitio, y quizas prueba de ello son los votos que recibió. No fueron exagerados, pero algo es algo, considerando la cantidad de personas que visitan Meta.

Comment: Gracias kenny por tu respuesta. Mi mentalidad ha cambiado en estos 9 meses que han pasado.. era muy novato cuando hice la pregunta y mira donde he llegado!  Obligar no es bueno para inculcar. Pero a veces si que me gustaria que les saltase un alert cada 5 segundos diciendo, "no has leido el tour!" XD

Comment: @lois6b Y mira que la pregunta antigua que mencione es mia y pues alli aprendi bastante tambien, que ahora respondo como lo hice. Aparte de todo esto, me parece fantastico que este tema vuelva a estar activo en Meta y mejor si es de parte de un, ahora, moderador. Esto me indica que estas metido en tu rol y que hay preocupación por la calidad del sitio/preguntas. Cuando nos preocupamos y buscamos soluciones, las cosas mejoran. Creo que vamos por buen camino.

Comment: (es un poco chistoso, pero no me di cuenta de la antigüedad de la pregunta, aunque todo lo que publique no parece tan fuera de lugar)

Comment: El cambio de esta pregunta fue a raiz de una de esta mañana cerrada como duplicado de esta :P