# ¿Se podría hacer más participativa e inmersiva la experiencia de la página de recorrido?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Soy nuevo en Stack Overflow en español y en general en Stack Exchange. La modalidad de la página me agrada bastante y espero contribuir mucho desde ahora. En los pocos días que he estado por acá, me he dado cuenta de que hay muchas preguntas de muy baja calidad que en su mayoría son puestas en espera o cerradas, ya que la pregunta no es clara, o no se ha incluído el ejemplo mínimo, está en inglés, etc.

Todos estas características de las cuales carecen este tipo de preguntas, se abordan en la página de recorrido. Lo curioso es que la mayoría de usuarios que hacen este tipo de preguntas tienen 1 de reputacion y 0 medallas, lo cual significa que ni siquiera se dignaron a "leer" esta página.

Como se plantea en [esta pregunta de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2243/deshabilitar-cierre-de-preguntas-recientes#2243) hay un posible problema con los usuarios nuevos y sus preguntas que se están cerrando demasiado rápido.

**EDIT**

Gracias a los comentarios he cambiado un poco el enfoque de la pregunta para que no este orientada a "restringir" sino a "mejorar". Para ilustrar mejor mi punto, tengo dos simples ejemplos de preguntas.

Estas preguntas se formularon el 28 de junio de 2017 y son un mero ejemplo, asi como estas hay muchas.

- En el [caso 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82203/runtime-error-security-error-ionic#comment151903_82203) el usuario nuevo no visitó la página de recorrido,
  su pregunta no tenía un ejemplo minimo y no obtuvo ni comentarios ni
  respuestas.
- En el [caso 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82184/error-al-borrar-un-registro-en-laravel) el usuario nuevo si visitó la página de recorrido, 
  su pregunto si tenía un ejemplo minimo y si obtuvo varios comentarios
  y una posible respuesta correcta.

Como bien me comentó toledano, ni la lectura ni la comprensión de la información en la página de recorrido mejora directamente la calidad de las preguntas (algo en lo que estoy muy de acuerdo), pero en un día cualquiera, en dos preguntas cualquiera (como mi ejemplo) podemos ver que influye en alguna medida. Entonces surge la pregunta, en el futuro, ¿podría ser una prioridad cambiar la experiencia de la página de recorrido para mejorar la calidad de las preguntas?

Comment: La lectura del tour no garantiza la comprensión -> la comprensión del tour no garantiza la calidad. Por la graduación perdimos muchos revisores, pero poco a poco el número se irá recuperando y revisaremos más rápido.

Comment: Concuerdo 100% contigo. Pero entonces: supongo que esa página esta allí, por que se considera que su lectura podría incrementar el adecuado uso del sitio en algún minimo porcentaje, de otra forma, sería mejor dejar que los usuarios acudieran al Centro de Ayuda por ellos mismos. Mi pregunta va orientada a que el recurso (el tour en la página de recorrido) existe y que podríamos aprovechar mejor este recurso.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, @toledano respondió a tu pregunta. Seguirán exisitiendo usuarios que aunque se avienten el recorrido no sepan ni cómo hacer una pregunta ni poco acercada a lo decente. Lo que sí podemos hacer es orientarlos a agregar segmentos de código, resultados esperados, a tomar el recorrido, a revisar el centro de ayuda, considero que eso es mejor que forzar a alguien a ver una página que no se sabe si tiene el tiempo o las ganas de revisar.

Comment: Concuerdo con @Flxtr, mejor orientar a cada usuario que restringir.

Comment: La pregunta que haces al final no es clara. ¿Qué tipo de cambio esperas ver? ¿Cómo podría la experiencia del tour mejorar la calidad de la pregunta? Creo que el [tour], [ask] y [mcve] son __recursos__ que contribuyen a la creación del contenido de calidad. Al final, lo que garantiza la calidad del sitio son las herramientas de moderación. De verdad, hay que confiar más en este proceso. La "revisión" es una habilidad que puede mejorarse, con la práctica, preguntas como esta, el chat, etc.

Comment: Veo que cambiaste el enfoque. Comparto tu preocupación para mejorar las preguntas de baja calidad y la cantidad de preguntas que quedan en espera... Pero, solamente estás trayendo 2 ejemplos de preguntas. Ahora, yo podría traerte ejemplos de usuarios con 1k+ de reputación que hacen preguntas de baja calidad. Creo que esa parte está un poco floja en el planteo... Sin embargo, estás argumentando que sólo la lectura del [tour] hace que se mejore (no concuerdo), pero luego planteas "*cambiar la experiencia de la página*". **¿cambiar algo que funciona?** Y ¿cómo? ¿cuál es la propuesta?

Comment: Que bueno ver más comentarios, veo que hay preocupación por esto. Yo no propongo garantizar la calidad del sitio, que para eso esta la revisión y moderación, y confío en esos procesos. Yo progongo mejorar la calidad de las preguntas de nuevos usuarios. Apoyo la declaracion de que la reputación no garantiza preguntas de buena calidad, por eso mis ejemplos fueron de personas con nada de reputación. El tipo de cambio que espero ver o una propuesta sería captar la atención de los nuevos usuarios con un video o animaciones o no sé, algo que las haga pensar: "tengo que ver esto antes de preguntar".

Comment: El famoso dicho: "Mejor prevenir que lamentar". Una analogía pequeña: "es mejor definir bien los requerimientos y escribir buen código, que estar buscando y arreglando bugs después. Pero por supuesto, parte de desarrollar software es tener fases de pruebas para buscar errores y corregirlos, mejor si es en parejas o grupos." Yo solo quiero generar debate positivo y sano para saber si podemos sacar más provecho a algo que ya funciona, no cambiarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Bajo mi punto de vista su primera publicacion respecto al titulo es mas acertado:

> **¿Se podría restringir la creación de preguntas a quienes no han leído la página de recorrido?**

por poderse pienso que si se podria, otra cosa es que se quiera hacer, pero sin dar muchas vueltas, pienso que su enfoque es correcto, aunque eso de restringir puede sonar un poco "radical" aun asi, yo no lo veo de tal manera, es mas, alguna vez he comentado de mi creencia de que si se implementara una especie de "pop" para cuando alguien que no cuenta con la medalla por leer el tour, quiera realizar una pregunta que se le abra el tour y hasta que no lo "lea", no pueda realizar la misma, cierto es que nada garantiza que este lo lea, es como el **EULA** "*End User License Agreement*", en el software pero esta ahi.

*Claro que esto no garantizaria nada*, pero seguro que ayuda mas, que no leerlo en el caso de hacerlo, en la mayoria de los casos si que ayudaria, hasta es muy posible que marque una gran diferencia y sea de utilidad para muchos que por ser nuevos no han leido el tour o no saben de su existencia (por cualquier motivo).

Ayudandolos si no a hacer una pregunta de diez en todos los casos, si a incrementar la calidad de la misma, o eso opino.

En definitiva pienso que haria mas bien que mal el "incitarlos" a leer el tour si no se cuenta con la medalla a la hora de formular un pregunta, ademas de mostrar algunos conceptos como las etiquetas ect.

---

**Aparte:**

una pregunta mal formulada ect, trae con sigo mucho mas trabajo para la comunidad.

- perdida de tiempo de los usuarios en leer una pregunta "mala".
- perdida de tiempo en intentar corregirla.
- perdida de tiempo en comentar que **lea** el tour, ect.
- se amplia la lista de preguntas para cerrar en la pila ect.

asi que, un "pop" con el tour, no afecta en nada a la comunidad y puede traer muchos beneficios, si acaso podria "molestar" la primera vez que al usuario nuevo le sale el tour, pero no es ni de lejos comparable al trabajo de mas que genera en la comunidad una mala pregunta, o simplemente una pregunta que tiene fallos que se podrian evitar con una simple leida del tour, como puede ser el uso de etiquetas de forma manual o saber que existen, y aunque es sistema automatico para los tag es muy bueno no siempre acierta, y si este falla en una pregunta mediocre pues la misma suma puntos para el cierre o -1 ect.

Pero claro abra de todo como puede ser que algunos les guste cerrar preguntas en su tiempo libre, hacer comentarios ofencivos hacia una mala pregunta, hasta hacerse el gracioso, que de todo existe, y me parece bien, cada loco con su tema, pero es posible que existan muchos mas que prefieran leer una buena pregunta o lo mas decente posible y no emplear su tiempo en lo mencionado anteriormente, y usarlo en su lugar para intentar responderla u otra cosa.

Comment: realmente no es una restriccion, como tal, por lo menos no es una cosas radical, pues una vez que salte el "pop" con el tour lo "lees" o lo desplazas hasta el final y listo, ya puedes preguntar. Saludos

Comment: @Kenny Barrera aunque no es lo mismo que usted pregunta esta es una de las preguntas que encontre en la cual se mueve alrededor del tema del tour para hacerlo mas visible "o eso se intentaba de alguna manrea" https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1767/incluyamos-dentro-del-tour-alguna-informaci%C3%B3n-acerca-de-las-etiquetas-para-promo como por ejemplo que los nuevo usuarios conozcan algunas caracteristicas como la edicion de etiquetas desde el primer momento por si alguno quiere colaborar con el sitio de esa manera ect. Saludos