# ¿Es posible implementar una nueva caracteristica que guíe en el proceso de crear preguntas de calidad?

Tags: característica-nueva, preguntas, interfaz-de-usuario

Se me ha ocurrido que se podría anexar un un botón en el formulario de edición al momento de crear una pregunta que despliegue algo así como un modal que vaya guiando al usuario en el proceso, cajas de texto que muestre cosas como:

- **Detalla aquí tu problema**
- **Anexa aquí parte de tu código**
- **Describe que has hecho para solucionarlo**
- **Cita algún elemento de consulta previo**
- **Te proponemos estas etiquetas** *«En base al texto del usuario»*

Consejos y recomendaciones en el momento en el que se realiza la pregunta, como «recuerda plantear tu pregunta de manera interrogativa» o cosas así. Obviamente un botón para uso opcional, pero que quizás haga mucho mas dinámica la creación de preguntas por parte de  usuarios con pocas bases en este aspecto.

Comment: ¡Gran idea! A buen seguro ayudaría muchísimo a los nuevos usuarios.

Comment: La idea es buena, pero estoy seguro que no será implementada.