# Mejoremos el recuadro "Cómo preguntar" de cada pregunta nueva

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Aun cuando estemos en el tema y la euforia de las elecciones, vengo con lo siguiente.
Hace poco, [NekoOs](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23643/nekoos) propuso [implementar una nueva caracteristica](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2262/es-posible-implementar-una-nueva-caracteristica-que-gu%C3%ADe-en-el-proceso-de-crear) para ayudar a los usuarios nuevos a mejorar la calidad de sus preguntas, y por lo tanto, mejorar la calidad del sitio (y supongo que la idea surgió de la baja calidad de algunas preguntas en el sitio últimamente). La idea era tener una especie de caja de texto (según sus propias palabras) que guiará al usuario en la creación de la pregunta. Los comentarios y los votos de la publicación reflejan que realmente es una buena idea, pero que al parecer es muy difícil implementarla.

Mi propuesta es tomar la idea de NekoOs y usarla en el recuadro amarillo que esta en el lado derecho superior cada vez que se quiere hacer una pregunta. Actualmente lo tenemos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, podemos tomar la idea y agregar algunas cosas en ese recuadro, justo debajo de lo que esta en negrita, algo así como:

> - Tu pregunta tiene que describir tu problema y debe ser específica, clara y breve
> - Explica lo mejor que puedas tu problema
> - Si es necesario, incluye parte de tu código para exponer mejor tu pregunta
> - Describe que has hecho para solucionarlo

(toda esta lista fue idea de NekoOs)

Hace muy poco tuve la intención de publicar una pregunta en *Software Recommendations* y me percate que en la página de creación de la pregunta, en el lado derecho superior tienen el siguiente recuadro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad me la pense dos veces antes de publicar mi pregunta, porque no había pensado aún en todas esas características.

Ya que, a diferencia de lo que proponia NekoOs, esto parece un poco más viable (que solo es agregar este texto, y no crear algo nuevo desde cero), mi sugerencia es agregar estas opciones a este recuadro para ayudar en la calidad de las preguntas del sitio.

Comment: En realidad mucha de la información que colocas ya aparece cuando estás formulando una pregunta.

Comment: He quitado la etiqueta de característica nueva pues se está presentando una idea para ser discutida, siendo que característica nueva debería ser usada para peticiones concretas. Sugiero que termines tu pregunta con una consulta concreta y que edites el título para que sea realmente un resumen del contenido de la pregunta. Así como está el título, se antoja responder con un "Sí podemos" pero ¿y luego?

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @Rubén, he cambiado lo que me ha parecido y espero que funcione mejor asi.

Comment: Un detalle a resaltar es que el sitio tiene una alcance más amplio que sólo programación. Véase [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)

Comment: @Rubén No había visto esa pregunta, pero la verdad es muy buena. En ese caso, la pregunta que actualmente leemos: "¿Tu pregunta es sobre programación?" ¿tambien debería ser sometida a debate? Porque el alcance del sitio es mucho mas que eso y se podría interpretar que si mi pregunta no es de programación, quizas debería pensar antes de preguntar.

Comment: Yo creo que sí, de hecho, tal vez deberíamos tener primero ese debate antes que el de cambiar el recuadro.

Comment: Fantástica iniciativa, voto por ella. Dado que hay tantas publicaciones en inglés, se podría añadir un _recuerda que el idioma de esta comunidad es el español_ :)